# No sound Ubuntu 20.04 Lenovo Yoga 7i

Tags: sound

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a new Lenovo Yoga 7i.   I'm not getting any sound from my speakers Settings - Sound - Output Device  shows Dummy Output so it looks like Ubuntu is not detecting my sound device.  Windows showed that the sound driver was realtek

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Lenovo Yoga 7i 14ITL - Intel Core i7 :( In my case Sound mentions sof-hda-dsp but doesn't work. However using headphones will output sound properly.

Answer (score 1):

[This "hack" from the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_Yoga_7i#Speaker_audio) for the Lenovo Yoga 7i helped me. I'm currently running Arch, but it is something that can be tried on other distro bases.  No guarantees, but it might be worth a try.

> ### Speaker audio
>
> This laptop requires firmware in order for the soundcard to work. [See Advanced Linux Sound Architecture#ALSA firmware](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#ALSA_firmware).
>
> Due to [this bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208555), the speakers do not work without modification. They do however work after suspending to RAM **if** audio playback is started within a short period of time of resuming (about 7 seconds), but they stop working if playback is interrupted for longer than this period of time. This allows for a hackish solution:
>
> 1. Make sure to [activate S3 sleep](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_Yoga_7i#Activating_S3_sleep).
> 2. Create a shell script to briefly suspend and then keep playing silent audio in the background to keep the speakers alive, for example:
>
> ```
> activate_audio
> ```
>
> ```bsh
> #!/bin/bash
> sudo rtcwake -m mem -s 1
> while true
> do
>   echo -n -e '\x00' | padsp tee /dev/audio
>   sleep 5
> done
> ```
>
> 3. Bind this script to a key, or execute it automatically after logging in.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 21.04 and using Lenovo Yoga 7i . S3 is activated 
I am getting `[    0.185836] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)`. After running your script the screen goes off for 2 seconds but sound is not working. Please help. Already tried thousands of other solution, nothing works ! . More information script is printing `tee: /dev/audio: Connection refused`

Comment: Update, looks like /dev/audio may not work in Ubuntu 21, so  I tired other ways of playing random sound from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465624/how-to-pipe-dev-urandom-to-linux-sound-output but that didn't work either. Its printing `Playing raw data '/dev/random' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo` on terminal but no sound coming from speakers

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  It turns out that the fix is in for several major distros.  Ubuntu 20.10 (kernel 5.13 after update) and Manjaro 21 & Fedora 34 (kernel 5.14 after update) now have working speaker audio!  So you now have your pick of deb, rpm, or arch systems, but the latest (and updated) Ubuntu should fix the speaker audio now.

Comment: @drepek I have updated to Ubuntu 21.10 5.13.0-20-generic and sound is not working. Please advise. It works via bluetooth though

Comment: I'm personally running Fedora 34, but sound working on Ubuntu 21.10 after updating to kernel 5.13 is according to a report from this kernel.org bug report thread: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208555  Was it a fresh install?  If possible, I would personally try a fresh install of 21.10 (not a dist-upgrade) and then update to the new stable kernel.

Comment: Also, the fix (essentially a kernel patch) is even confirmed on the Arch Wiki's updated information: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_Yoga_7i#Speaker_audio

Comment: Tried running 21.10 via live USB.. no sound detected ! I am on Lenovo Yoga 7 14ITL5. It is detecting sound device as Speaker - Tiger Lake LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller. @drepek Please advise

Comment: Got a software update from Ubuntu to upgrade to  5.13.0-21-generic. Finally sound is working !! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This Linux/Ubuntu audio/sound problem seems to be caused by Linux kernel incompatibility with **Realtek ALC287** chipset. So this will happen not only for Lenovo Yoga 7i but any laptop or device using this specific chipset.

In my Lenovo Yoga 7i system:

- built-in speakers: not working
- headphones connected to 3.5 mm jack: audio output works
- headset with mic connected to 3.5 mm jack: *not yet tested*
- TV audio output connected to HDMI over USB-C: *not yet tested*
- Bluetooth speakers: work (should be anyway)

See: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208555

Other resources:

- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/No-sound-from-speakers-using-Realtek-ALC287/m-p/5061232
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611530/how-can-i-get-my-unsupported-sound-card-to-work-with-alsa
- https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-lib/issues/76